# Is there documentation for the command line interface of the Marvell Disk Storage Utility?

Tags: ssd, documentation, hybrid-storage

The [Marvell](http://www.marvell.com/) Disk Storage Utility (DSU), as required to enable and configure HybridDuo mode with a [Highpoint Rocket Hybrid 1220](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/rockethybrid-1220-ssd-caching,2936.html), [Asus P8P67DLX](http://uk.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8P67_DELUXE/) or [Lycom PE-115H](http://www.lycom.com.tw/6G%20SATA.htm) has a command line interface, but neither these websites nor the Marvell website seem to have documentation on the CLI.

If anyone has found the documentation for this, I would be very interested to know where it was located.

While I love the concept of the [Marvell 88SE9130](http://www.marvell.com//storage/system-solutions/assets/Marvell-88SE9130-Product-Brief.pdf) chip, caching a large cheap hard drive on a smaller fast SSD, the web based management console is a bit of a nightmare, so I wonder if it might be quicker and simpler to use the CLI, if only I could find some documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of the Marvell software you're using, but I have an HP Gen 10 MicroServer with a Marvell controller.  I installed the [Marvell Storage Utility](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_17d87af242a144cbb3a954352c&swEnvOid=4231) on it, and it provided a tool called mvsetup.exe:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Marvell\storage\interface>mvsetup
CLI Version: 4.1.10.16   RaidAPI Version: 5.0.0.1061
Welcome to RAID Command Line Interface.

>
```

Typing `help` gives a list of commands that can be used.  `help <command>` gives more detailed help.

One useful command is `smart -p <id>`, which gives the SMART information for a particular disk (note: ids start at 0).

Typing `quit` exits the tool.

This version (and perhaps others) supports commands after the program name, e.g. `mvsetup smart -p0`.

Note: according to [Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukbsdt1/boss-s-1/boss_s1_ug_publication/supported-boss-s1-cli-commands?guid=guid-2cf1f2e7-c14a-429d-a328-c0f42a094ea6&lang=en-us), in Linux/ESXi, the tool seems to be called `mvcli`.

Comment: Wow, I don't think even have this card any more. It's certainly not in any of the machines I still use. Thanks anyway, and I hope you get a necromancer badge for this. *8')